# Given $2$ subgroups $N,K < G$ with $N$ normal in $G$ and $N \cap K = \{e\}$ and $G = NK$. Prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $K$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

The problem statement is as follows

> $G$ is a group. $N,K < G$. $N \lhd G$. $N \cap K = \{e\}$ and $G = NK$. Show that $G/N \cong K$.

---

This seems like an application of the $1^{\text{st}}$ Isomorphism Theorem to me. What I understand about the theorem is that if given a normal subgroup $N \lhd G$ then to show that $G/N$ is isomorphic to some other group it suffices to show that there is a surjective homomorphism from $G$ onto this other group where the kernel of the homomorphism is $N$. Correct?

So, in this context it seems that we would want to find a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $K$ whose kernel is $N$? Given this, would the homomorphism be something like $\phi: G \to K$ defined by $$\phi(g) = \begin{cases} g & \text{if}\ g \in K \\ e & \text{if}\ g \in N \end{cases}$$ That way this function would simply preserve any element of $G$ that is in $K$ and send any element of $G$ that is in $N$ to the identity. Hence the kernel of the function being all of $N$.

After trying to prove that this is a homomorphism I'm seeing that it is not. Since given $g,g' \in G$ if $g \in K$ and $g' \in N$ then $\phi(gg')$ is not necessarily in $K$ but $\phi(g)\phi(g') = (g)(e) = g \in K$.

---

Given that, I'd like to know if this is at least the correct approach and I suppose if anyone has any hints as to what I should be considering when constructing this homomorphism (provided, again, the approach is correct) that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here $$G\cong N\rtimes K,$$ an internal semidirect product.

Comment: Given $g \in G$, we know that $g=nk$ for $n \in N$ and $k \in K$. Then define $\phi(g) := k$. Is this a group homomorphism? Recall that $N$ is normal in $G$, and $N \cap K = \{e\}$.

Comment: You could also try showing that $k\mapsto kN$ is a well-defined map $K\to G/N$.

Comment: @azif00 I tried proving $\phi$ a homomorphism first by saying let $g=nk,/ g'=n'k' \in G$ where $n,n' \in N$ and $k,k' \in K$ Then we have: $$\phi(gg') = \phi(nkn'k') = \phi(n(kn')k') = \phi(n(n'k)k') = \phi((nn')(kk') = kk' = \phi(nk)\phi(n'k')$$ But after looking at it I see I misinterpreted the third equality holding as associativity. I'm guessing we need to utilize the fact that $gng^{-1} = n$ to prove $\phi$ a homomorphism here? Since $k \in K < G$ hence $knk^{-1} =n$ However all I've seen is that since $n = knk^{-1}$ we can show that $\phi(nkn'k') = \phi(knk'n') by substitution

Comment: @Shaun I've yet to encounter that term 'semidirect product' or the symbol there so I won't be able to make good use of that fact, I don't believe. Though I do appreciate the suggestion, I'm sure it is a simplifying one indeed. One that I'm sure I'll be able to make sense of soon enough!

Comment: @azif00 As well I can see that the kernel of this homomorphism is indeed $N$. Since $g \in N\ \text{if}\ k = e$ so if $k = e$ we have $\phi(g) = \phi(ne) = e$

Comment: @azif00 I just remembered that the condition of normality of $N$ in $G$ can be expressed as $gN = Ng$ for all $g \in G$ and so given that would my original attempt at proving that $\phi$ is a homomorphism be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your original attempt is not correct because it is not necessarily that $G$ is the union of $N$ and $K$, which means that not all elements of $G$ must be in $N$ or in $K$.

For each $g\in G$, since $G=NK$, there exists $n\in N$ and $k\in K$ such that $g=nk$. And because $N\cap K=\{e\}$, the choice of $n$ and $k$ are unique, for suppose that there exists $x\in N$ and $y\in K$ such that $nk=xy$, then we have $x^{-1}n=yk^{-1}\in N\cap K$ which implies that $x=n$ and $y=k$. Therefore the homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow K$ defined by $g\mapsto k$ is well-defined.

Next we want to check that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
Let $g,g'\in G$. Then $g=n_1k_1$ and $g'=n_2k_2$ where $n_1,n_2\in N$ and $k_1,k_2\in K$. Since $N$ is normal, $k_1N=Nk_1$ and therefore $k_1n_1=n_3k_1$ for some $n_3\in N$.
Now
$$\begin{align}
\phi(gg')&=\phi(n_1k_1n_2k_2)\\
&=\phi(n_1n_3k_1k_2)\\
&=k_1k_2\\
&=\phi(g)\phi(g').
\end{align}$$

It is straightforward to see that $\ker\phi=\{nk:n\in N \text{ and }k=e\}=N$ and for each $k\in K$, $\phi(k)=k$. Therefore you can conclude by using the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I ended up coming up with.. just less succinct and with many more eraser marks on my paper! Thanks for the confirmation Alan, and for the proof that the homomorphism is well-defined. It's a nice reminder that I shouldn't just assume any construction is well-defined but should prove it first.